# What's the meaning of [1] in matplotlib's subplots()?

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

Some time ago I've seen a usage of matplotlib's `subplots()` like this:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()[1]
```

and I've used it for some reason in my own script, but unfortunately I've entirely forgotten the meaning of `[1]` in it (I should have added a comment in my code!). Could someone tell me what it does?

Comment: are you sure that line of code runs? Either `fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()` or `ax1 = plt.subplots()[1]`

Comment: @QuangHoang With "fig" it gives me a "TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not iterable" error; deleting [1] solves this problem (but I need to know what happens if I delete it!). But with "ax1" alone [1] worked without any errors. Perhaps, I should have used only "ax1" in my question for better clarity.

Comment: `plt.subplots()` returns a tuple `(fig_instance, axis_instances)`. `[1]` is just tuple indexing.

Comment: @QuangHoang Ah! So, [1] is indexing `axis_instances`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to explain what the `[1]` is and why perhaps it's not what you actually intend to get, step-by-step. Also, I'm assuming you don't literally run `fig, ax = plt.subplots()[1]`, as that should give an error, because there is nothing to unpack in the second element of this object. I'll use the example of 4 subplots, (2,2).

So, first of all, `plt.figure()` returns a `tuple`, with a `figure` and a collection of `Axes` (depending on how many rows and cols you pass as arguments). So:

```
a = plt.subplots(2,2)  # 2,2 is an example, it could also be empty, so same as (1,1); the below would still hold
type(a)
len(a)
```

this returns `tuple` of `len` = 2. If you now check what is the first element of the tuple, you'll see it's the actual empty figures (graphically depicted):

```
a[0]
```

[image: Empty fig]

while the second element is the array of `Axes (an` Axes` is the region of the image with the data space, or how I like to think about it "the actual representation of a set of data on a given figure").

```
a[1]

array([[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7fe02397c650>,
    <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7fe022c1e4d0>],
   [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7fe022deb210>,
    <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7fe0239b5ed0>]],
  dtype=object)
```

Now, if you are explicitly limiting your selection to the second element of the `plt.subplots()` tuple, that means you are only grabbing the Axes to unpack into `fig` and `ax`.

```
fig, ax = a[1]
fig
```

this returns:

```
array([<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7fe02397c650>,
   <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7fe022c1e4d0>],
  dtype=object)

ax
```

this returns:

```
array([<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7fe022deb210>,
   <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x7fe0239b5ed0>],
  dtype=object)
```

So essentially you assigned the `Axes` of the first row to the `fig` object, and the `Axes` of the second row to the `ax` object. Depending on how your plotting function goes on next, it is possible that these subplots are either never used, or you somehow don't get an error because you chose a specific subplot size. Of course, if your goal is to actually only use the second element of `plt.subplots()`, i.e. the set of `Axes`, you can do that. But then `fig` will no longer actually be a figure. Just to demonstrate what happens when I use the whole plotting pipeline like you suggested (using the `iris` dataset for example):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)[1]
ax[0].scatter(x=iris.sepal_length, y=iris.sepal_width) # Filling in the first `Axes`
ax[1].scatter(x=iris.sepal_width, y=iris.sepal_length) # Filling in the second `Axes`
plt.show()
```

[image: 4 figures but only 2 axes are filled in]

Finally, if you want to read more about it, the `matplotlib` [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html?highlight=subplots#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots) on subplots() has a few more examples, and also shows that `plt.subplots()`, regardless of the shape you pass into it, always returns a tuple of `fig, ax` (where "ax : axes.Axes object or array of Axes objects").

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!